# Fill a form on one website and second website automatically grabs it

Tags: forms, rules

I have two websites, which have exactly same forms and fields. When the user fills the form on first website, the content gets published on first website. I manually do it on another website. Is there any simpler way of doing this? Is it possible that it automatically grabs the data from 1st website as user fills the form?

Comment: Can people fill out the form on both sites? If so you could potentially run into problems with submission IDs getting out of sync. You can use things like services and feeds to pass data between sites but I'm not sure how much support those things have for forms. This is not a simple task and it is too hard to properly answer without having complete information about your websites. There are a lot of possible solutions for sharing data, it comes down to the specifics of the site as to which is the best.

Comment: For example we know nothing about your form. Node form, webform, custom form, something else. We don't know your business rules. We don't know how each of the two sites are used. And there are a bunch more things we don't know that would help in determining possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a bit of JQuery. Assuming your form action is action1.php which is on site 1 and you have another handler action2.php on site 2:

```
$('#form_id').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();  // Stop default handling
    var $form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'action2.php',  // Submit to the second site
        data: $th.serialize(),
        success: function(){
            $th.submit();    // Submit to the first site
        }
    });
});
```

And now the form will be submitted to both sites and they will both handle it

Comment: On which site do I have to use this code? and in the url, actually I can't give action2.php as it is not on the same machine.

Comment: you can put it on any of the sites, or on both sites if you need either site's form to submit to itself and to the other. I know you can't give action2.php, you need to give the full submit url: http://www.mysite.com/.....

Comment: This will also not work in the (admittedly uncommon) case that the user has javascript disabled.